# Use of Taylor series to speed up computation

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, taylor-series

In math, [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) are important to get approximations of functions, with polynomials of small degree.

I wanted to see how such an approximation can be helpful, for example in order to speed up computations.  Let's use the famous Taylor series:

```
log(1+x) = x + 0.5 * x^2 + (error term)
```

Morally, computing the value of a polynomial of degree 2 should be much faster than computing a `log`.

Thus a code to test this:

```
import numpy, time

def f(t):
    return t + 0.5 * t ** 2
f = numpy.vectorize(f)  

s = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    x = numpy.random.rand(100000) 
    numpy.log(1 + x)
print time.time() - s          # 0.556999921799 seconds

s = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    x = numpy.random.rand(100000)
    f(x)
print time.time() - s          # arghh! 4.81500005722 seconds
```

**Why is the polynomial method 10 times slower than the actual log? I expected the contrary.**

*PS: This question is probably in the middle of SO and math.SE.*

Comment: Have you had a look at how numpy computes log? Chances are numpy's log() is pretty much optimized itself

Comment: With `numpy.log(1 + x)` you are using NumPy's array programming that operates in actual vectorized way, whereas with np.vectorize as the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) states : `"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance"`. So, the equivalent way would be to directly use `x` there : `x + 0.5 * x ** 2` upon replacing `f(x)`.

Comment: Taylor series will have convergence issues for arguments that are far away from the expansion point.  That's true for all extrapolations.

Comment: @duffymo well, that's not true for ALL extrapolations. Polynomials are quite close to "long enough" Taylor expansions at any point.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Interpolation is far safer.  Extrapolation makes an assumption about the behavior of the curve beyond stated limits.  It's easy to think of examples where that is not a good idea.  If extrapolation were as safe as you're implying I'd use it to predict the behavior of the stock market and be rich.

Comment: @duffymo I think you missed my point. You said that ALL TS expansions are bad, which is not true. Nevertheless I did not say all extrapolations were safe.

Comment: I never said that.  Please re-read.  I pointed out that all Taylor series expansions have convergence issues for arguments that are far away from the expansion point x0.   f(x) = f(x0) + ...

Comment: Well would that be true for the Taylor series expansion of a linear function for example ?

Comment: Its almost always better to compute polynomals via Horner's rule. In your case t*(1.0+0.5*t). You've used the exponentiation operator **, which could be slow.

Comment: Maybe Python Numpy is a too high level language / too much optimised, but my goal is to do a program (maybe I should try C ?) that will blatantly show that a order-2 Taylor expansion of log will be much faster than log itself. I should add this in question.

Comment: True for all the typical functions: sine, cosine, exponential, etc.  That's the nature of Taylor series, not the function.

Comment: Note that numpy also exports `log1p` which computes `log(1 + x)` but with higher accuracy when x is near zero. But it's not any faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python+Numpy, it's probably optimized here and there, and so it's impossible to really benchmark `log(1+x)` vs `x + 0.5 * x^2`.
So I moved to C++.

## Result:

> Time per operation with log: 19.57 ns
> Time per operation with order-2 Taylor expansion of log: 3.73 ns

So roughly a  x5 factor !

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N (1000*1000*100)
#define NANO (1000*1000*1000)

int main()
{
  float *x = (float*) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
  float y;
  float elapsed1, elapsed2;
  clock_t begin, end;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    x[i] = (float) (rand() + 1) / (float)(RAND_MAX);

  begin = clock();
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    y = logf(x[i]);
  end = clock();
  elapsed1 = float(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / N * NANO;

  begin = clock();
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    y = x[i] + 0.5 * x[i] * x[i];  
  end = clock();
  elapsed2 = float(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / N * NANO;

  std::cout << "Time per operation with log: " << elapsed1 << " ns\n";  
  std::cout << "Time per operation with order-2 Taylor epansion: " << elapsed2 << " ns";

  free(x);

}
```

Comment: It can be benchmarked in python, the issue is you were comparing numpy's optimized code with raw python.  When comparing basic python to basic python, or numpy implementation to numpy the speed of the approximation is apparent.

Comment: True, but comparing "basic python log" vs  "basic python taylor expansion" gives your `1.1818947792053223
 / 0.8402454853057861` ratio which is ~ 1.4. This is quite low, I expected more a x5 or x10 ratio, thus the C/C++ version to see more what happens...

Comment: Yes, not too surprising with the overhead from the interpreter. The numpy version shows 0.07202601432800293 vs 0.0019881725311279297, which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy's vectorized operations will almost always be faster than any attempted optimizations in your own code.  As @Divakar mentioned, `vectorize` is really just a convenient way around writing a for loop, so your code will be slower than numpy's native code.

Replacing numpy's optimized routines with standard python code shows that your method is about the same speed.

```
import math, numpy, time


def f(t):
    return t + 0.5 * t ** 2

x = numpy.random.rand(1000000)

s = time.time()
for num in x:
    math.log(1 + num)
print (time.time() - s  )  

s = time.time()
for num in x:
    f(num)
print (time.time() - s)
```

result:

```
1.1951053142547607
1.3485901355743408
```

The approximation is only slightly slower, but exponentiation is very expensive.  Replacing `t ** 2` with `t*t` gives a good improvement, and allows the approximation to slightly outperform python's `log`

```
1.1818947792053223
0.8402454853057861
```

Edit: Alternatively, since the big lesson here is optimized scientific libraries will outperform a handcoded solution almost any day of the week, here's the taylor series approximation with numpy's vectorized operations, which is by far the fastest.  Note the only big change is that `vectorize` isn't called on the approximation function, so numpy's vectorized operations are used by default.

```
import numpy, time

def f(t):
    return t + 0.5 * t ** 2

x = numpy.random.rand(1000000)
s = time.time()
numpy.log(1 + x)
print (time.time() - s)

s = time.time()
x = numpy.random.rand(100000)
f(x)
print (time.time() - s  )
```

result:

```
0.07202601432800293
0.0019881725311279297
```

There you have it, the vectorized approximation is over an order of magnitude faster than numpy's vectorized `log`.

Comment: Uh, most importantly, numpy.log is going to be implemented in C, whereas your function requires the Python interpreter.

Comment: @Max, exactly.  When the comparison is equal (log and approximation using numpy's vectorized functions), the function is much faster.

Comment: Very interesting to read. Conclusion: Numpy and Python are too high level / too optimized to be able to benchmark how a Taylor expansion of degree 2 is faster than a `log`. I'll do it again in plain C to see what happens.